# Making 2 Kafka JdbcSinkConnectors write to the same table with non-nullable columns?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm experimenting with having 2 JdbcSinkConnectors each write different columns of the same table. They'd both use the same primary key to upsert. E.g. given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public."foo" (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    bar bigint NOT NULL,
    baz bigint
)
```

The first connector writes `bar` and the second connector writes `baz`. If the second connector attempts to write first, it'll fail because `bar` is non-nullable, but it can just try again later. However, even if the first connector writes first, the second connector still fails. Here's the error:

```
ERROR: null value in column "bar" of relation "foo" violates not-null constraint 
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0
  INSERT INTO "foo" ("id","baz") VALUES (1,1)
  ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "baz"=EXCLUDED."baz"
was aborted:
  ERROR: null value in column "bar" of relation "foo" violates not-null constraint
```

The upsert fails because Postgres expects all non-nullable columns in the upsert. Is there a way to work around this? I don't want to use a default value for the non-nullable fields because I'd have to change a lot of queries and it's error-prone.

It looks like JdbcSinkConnector wasn't designed to be used like this, is this something that's discouraged?

Comment: can you add following line in ..do update set ...action list.  DO UPDATE SET "bar"=EXCLUDED."baz", "bar"=foo."bar"

Comment: 1) Your Kafka records need all the fields to exist 2) I think the suggested design here would be to use Debezium to read the Sink writer event then use a secondary sink that reads from the Debezium source to update the other table. Otherwise, you'd write a trigger, not an inline update query

Comment: @kus How would I do that with JdbcSinkConnector?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Isn't Debezium just for reading data? I don't understand what you mean, are there certain terms I should search for?

Comment: @LeoJiang can you share "pk.mode" and "pk.fields" configured value?

Comment: Also check if table definition has Primary Key. that may be additional issue if no primary key.